# PowerBI Fiscal YEAR

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a measure in PowerBI for fiscal year. I am starting with PowerBI, so my experience is very limited.

This gives a syntax error:

```
FiscalYear_ = IF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 9, YEAR(NOW()); YEAR(NOW()) + 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

KR 
M

Comment: That worked for my case. I just replaced the first comma for a semi-colon:

`FiscalYear_ = IF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 9; YEAR(NOW()); YEAR(NOW()) + 1) `

My local settings only allow me to work with semi-colon instead of commas. Is that your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in some locales comma is used as decimal separator, parameters separator in functions sometimes is not comma (,), but semicolon (;). This depends on your regional settings. But in your example, you mixed both separator types - there is a comma after `9` and semicolon after "value if true" parameter. You should fix the wrong one and the measure to be either:

```
FiscalYear_ = IF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 9, YEAR(NOW()), YEAR(NOW()) + 1)
```

or

```
FiscalYear_ = IF(MONTH(NOW()) <= 9; YEAR(NOW()); YEAR(NOW()) + 1)
```